# How to encapsulate the concept of a combination of generics into a new type?

Tags: c#, generics, types

Is there any way that one can encapsulate Dictionary to be a new type like DataDictionary so that instead of needing to change the definition in however many places it is used, it can be changed in only a few. Or should I just wrap this in another class that exposes only the aspects that I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary is not sealed so if you want a proper sub-type, do

```
class DataDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K,V>
{
}
```

And another option is :

```
class DataDictionary<K, V> 
{
   private Dictionary<K,V> _data;

}
```

Which gives you more freedom to design your own type.
And if you meant "How to eliminate the type-parameters", use something like:

```
class DataDictionary : Dictionary<string, int>
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***using*** directive on the top of your code file.

```
using DataDictionary = Dictionary<int,int>
```

But if you use this DataDictionary in a lot of code files, encapsulation or inheritance are much more preferred.